# Adapted classes of objects and left (right) exact functors

Tags: homological-algebra, sheaf-theory, homology-cohomology, derived-functors

I had a question about adapted classes of objects, I was confused by the definition and how it relates to left exact functors. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category with enough injectives, let $F: \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}$ be a left exact functor to an abelian category $\mathcal{B}$, to construct the right derived functor $RF$ of $F$ we take an object $X$ of $\mathcal{A}$ and embed it in an injective resolution

$0 \rightarrow X \rightarrow I^0 \rightarrow I^1 \rightarrow I^2 \cdots$,

and $R^iF(X)$ is the homology at the i-th spot of the complex

$0 \rightarrow F(I^0) \rightarrow F(I^1) \rightarrow F(I^2) \rightarrow \cdots$

right?

But then I was reading about adapted classes of objects, and the definition says:

*Let $F:\mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}$ be a left exact functor. A class of objects $\mathcal{R}$ in $\mathcal{A}$ is an **adapted class of objects** for $F$ if the following conditions are satisfied:*

*1 - $F$ maps any acyclic complex from $Kom^+(\mathcal{R}$) into an acyclic complex.*

...

Among other conditions, it also says that the class of injective objects is adapted to all left exact functors, so now I'm like if that's the case, if I take this part of the sequence

$I^0 \rightarrow I^1 \rightarrow I^2 \rightarrow \cdots$,

this is exact therefore acyclic no? if I apply the left exact functor $F$, I get

$F(I^0) \rightarrow F(I^1) \rightarrow F(I^2) \rightarrow \cdots$,

which would also be acyclic by the above definition? But wouldn't that make the right derived functor groups $R^iF(X) = 0$ for $i \geq 2$?

Comment: What book/article did you read this in?  References are always helpful for non-trivial questions :-)

Comment: The complex $I^0 \to I^1 \to \cdots$ is *not* exact (it fails to be exact at the $0$th place). @Peter: If memory serves, the notation of this question is that of Gelfand-Manin (who talk about adapted classes), I think that's a pretty safe bet.

Comment: It's Methods of homological algebra by Gelfand-Manin. @t.b. I thought the complex $X \rightarrow I^0 \rightarrow I^1 \rightarrow \cdots$ was the one that wasn't exact but acyclic? In any case going by that definition aren't the groups $R^iF(X) = 0$ for $i \geq 2$?

Comment: No, if you take an injective (or adapted) resolution of $X$ then by definition the complex $\cdots 0 \to 0 \to X \to I^0 \to I^1 \to \cdots$ is exact. If you throw away $X$ then the resulting complex $\cdots \to 0 \to 0 \to I^0 \to I^1 \to \cdots$ isn't exact anymore (the first morphism of an exact complex should be injective) and this can result in cohomology in all degrees. A good example of an adapted class are the flat modules, which are (by definition) those adapted to the tensor product. You can compute Tor by taking flat resolution of a module, not only by a projective resolution.

Comment: But if I forget about all that can I simply take any "higher" sequence $I^2 \rightarrow I^3 \rightarrow I^4 \rightarrow \cdots$? would that sequence be exact? or $I^3 \rightarrow I^4 \rightarrow I^5 \rightarrow \cdots$? I thought that "higher" terms in sequences were unaffected if I took out "lower" terms, the terms $I^2$, $I^3$, $I^4$ and the maps $d^1$, $d^2$, $d^3$ are still the same no? or do they change if I remove "lower" terms? @t.b. Thanks, you're giving me great insight into this

Comment: The sequence $I^0 \to I^1 \to I^2 \to \cdots$ is exact, but the sequence $\cdots \to 0 \to I^0 \to I^1 \to \cdots$ is not. The $0$ in front makes a difference!

Comment: I'm confused, t.b. says the sequence $I^0 \rightarrow I^1 \rightarrow I^2 \rightarrow \cdots$ is exact, but @ZhenLin says it isn't. I read another definition and it says that "left exact functors are exact on injective objects", so if I take for example $I^1 \rightarrow I^2 \rightarrow I^3 \rightarrow \cdots$ and apply the left exact functor $F$ I get the exact sequence $F(I^1) \rightarrow F(I^2) \rightarrow F(I^3) \rightarrow \cdots$. But doesn't that imply that $R^iF(X) = 0$ for $i \geq 2$? Then what would be the point of homology? Wouldn't that make homology trivial from degree 2 onwards?

Comment: @Luis: I said the *complex* $\cdots \to 0 \to 0 \to I^0 \to I^1 \to \cdots$ and by a bad habit and general sloppiness I suppressed the zeros on the left, as we are talking about things that live in $\operatorname{Kom}^+(\mathcal{A})$, after all. Zhen Lin is right: if you consider the diagram $I^0 \to I^1 \to \cdots$ as a sequence in $\mathcal{A}$, it *is* exact since there's a zero missing on the left, however, that's not what we're talking about, really. Concerning your second question: it does not imply that. The adaptedness condition only applies to exact *complexes* (zeros on the left).

Comment: I was curious, if the complex $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow I^0 \rightarrow I^1 \rightarrow \cdots$ is exact, can't I just filter through $A$ to get $0 \rightarrow I^0 \rightarrow I^1 \rightarrow I^2 \rightarrow \cdots$ exact? where the map from $0$ to $I^0$ is the composition of the map from $0$ to $A$ and the map from $A$ to $I^0$?